# Easy way to deploy a light Flask+Redis+Celery app?

Tags: flask, deployment, redis, celery, plotly-dash

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app (preferably for free, it's a small internal project and just want the app up and running).

In development, I start the app by:

Starting Redis:

`redis-server --port 6360`

Starting the Celery worker and Celery beat:

`celery -A tasks.schedule worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet`

and

`celery -A tasks.schedule beat --loglevel=INFO`

finally

`python app.py` or something.

Where are free or low cost hosting platforms where I can deploy an app like this easily?

Thanks!

I tried using Koyeb, but that platforms uses RabbitMQ as a broker, when I would prefer to use Redis.